# need android layout advise

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to create layout as attached below.

[image]

As you see i have added fixed buttons to bottom on the layout.
and now i have problem when content part has more than 9 elements.
While it is going to scroll, last elements are hiding back of the bottom buttons and not scrolling fully as below:

[image]

Please give me advise how to do it? Please notice i am not professional android developer.

I am now going to attach my xml layout files. Here you are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        app:tabGravity="fill" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ButtonsLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#F5F5F5"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:background="#808080" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer_button_icons_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#F5F5F5"
                android:drawablePadding="3dp"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_xxx"
                android:gravity="center|center"
                android:text="@string/footer_xxx"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/xxx_gray_darker"
                android:textSize="12sp" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/borderless_button"
                android:drawablePadding="3dp"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_xxx"
                android:gravity="center|center"
                android:text="@string/footer_xxx"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="12sp" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#F5F5F5"
                android:drawablePadding="3dp"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_xxx"
                android:gravity="center|center"
                android:text="@string/footer_xxx"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/xxx_gray_darker"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is a First Fragment layout xml of ViewPager**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="20dp"></GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding android:layout_above="@+id/ButtonsLinearLayout" to your ScrollView?

Comment: yes i have added it as @RRR said

Comment: I would suggest wrapping your fragment layout in a scrollview instead of the viewpager.

Comment: @TouchBoarder, i wonder why ViewPager not showing it is content while defining ViewPager inside ScroolView?

Comment: @AEMLoviji Take a look at the sample code from the Android developers, example on how to use ScrollView (NestedScrollView) with AppBarLayout https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/SupportDesignDemos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `android:layout_above` in your scrollView

```
<ScrollView android:layout_above="@id/ButtonsLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

your `ScrollView` should be above `LinearLayout` which consist `Buttons`.

Comment: Yes as you said i must set android:layout_above property to @id/ButtonsLinearLayout. But in this case i set this property not to ScrrolView but for ViewPager  as @Karthik said. Because when i am going to use scrrolview. it now showing anymore.

Comment: Its your choice which control you want to use. I just gave answer of your question. Yes if you are directly using `ViewPager`, set this property to `ViewPager`

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use ScrollView in view pager. Remove ScrollView for the ViewPager whose id is pager.

Comment: This is not an answer, you should comment on the question instead.

Comment: I wonder why ViewPager not showing it is content while defining ViewPager inside ScroolView?

Comment: check your adapter if your using pager adapter you can try this @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

Answer (score 0):

`paddingBottom` is what you want. Add `paddingBottom` to your `ScrollView` or any other layout which is the container of the items. The padding should be slightly greater than the height of the bottom strip.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="48dp">
```